# Can't get the value of Date Range Picker (Vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs-datepicker

I am a newbie in VueJS. I want to get the value of the date range that is selected and `console.log` it when the user clicks the button. However, whenever I click the button, the value printing in console is `null`. Kindly Help.

This is the code:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <VueRangedatePicker v-model="datepicker"></VueRangedatePicker>
    <button class="button" @click="showdata()" value="Test">Normal</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueRangedatePicker from "vue-rangedate-picker";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VueRangedatePicker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      datepicker: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showdata() {
      console.log("DATE PICKER", this.datepicker);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Code can be accessed [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-villani-1e5vi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) to work, a component needs to have a prop called `value` and emit an `input` event.

`VueRangedatePicker` doesn't [have](https://github.com/bliblidotcom/vue-rangedate-picker#available-events) that prop or event. Instead, it emits a `selected` event when it updates. You can [listen](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events) for it using `@selected`. For example:

```
<VueRangedatePicker @selected="updateDatePicker"></VueRangedatePicker>
```

```
  methods: {
    showdata() {
      console.log("DATE PICKER", this.datepicker);
      console.log("start: " + this.datepicker.start);
      console.log("end: " + this.datepicker.end);
    },
    updateDatePicker(value) {
      console.log("updating datepicker value");
      this.datepicker = value;
    }
```

See updated code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-jones-y1e5u?file=/src/App.vue:400-706).

Comment: Thank you very much.. It is now working, Really Thank you.